# How to scan integers from a file containing Strings too in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How would I get my scanner stream to read just the integers in

```
Jane    354
Jill    546
Jenny   718
Penny   125
```

The Scanner method `nextLine()` read both the name, and the number, so I suppose I could just parse it out, but I wanted to know if there were a way for `nextInt()` to skip the name and only read the numbers because it fails right away when it sees that it starts with a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `next()`, ignore its result and then use `nextInt()`? This should do exactly what you need if all your lines are in format you presented in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call scanner.next() and do nothing with it to skip the string, for instance:

```
// Scanner sc;
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    sc.next(); //Skip string
    int number = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Same thing Pshemo was saying, right? I think this'll work, since we're not expected to handle anything other than how this file is structured, but hopefully I'll learn how to write more flexible code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use scanner.nextLine() and then grab the int with a reg ex matcher

```
String mydata = scanner.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile([0-9]+);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find()){
    int num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: That's a little out of my scope at the moment. It would look pretty suspicious if I were using things I yet have no knowledge about. I think I can see what's going on, but I never even knew there were Pattern and Matcher classes or how to use them, until now.

Comment: If the format is consistent you could also use the String class method "split" on whitespace and grab the second result(the int) for each line.

Comment: And then parse it, and make store them as ints, but like I said, I would like to do things through the Scanner class, since that's what this assignment focuses on. I got another handy tip over from reddit.com/r/javahelp that said I could change the delimiter if I had to, so I think I'll go with the answer Pshemo and MrAzzaman came up with.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("some file here"));
while(read.hasNext()){
    if(read.next() instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println(read.next());
    }
}
```